# JQuery HTML5 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I have a simple form:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
                <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="login-form">
                  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                  <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                  </label>
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="login-but-sub">Sign in</button>
                </form>
          </div> <!-- form container -->
</div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

in an HTML 5 web app, (ember JS if it makes a diff),
the HTML 5 form validation as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) works perfectly.
I am attaching a JQuery event as such:

```
$(function(){
    /*Try to restore user once upon loading*/
    restore_user();
    App = Ember.Application.create({ 
                        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true, });

    client = new client()


    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.route('login');
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller) {
            console.log(client);
            if(!client.isLoggedIn()){
                this.transitionTo('login')
            }
        }
});
    $("#login-but-sub").submit(function(event){
    console.log("login clicked");
});

});
```

and the issue the event never seems to be fired...
If I change it to:

```
    $("body").submit(function(event){
```

or

```
    $("body").on('submit','body',function(event)
```

then it also works.
what is wrong with the first one?

Comment: the submit event is fired on the `<form>` and not on the `<button>`

Comment: @anderssonola that's OP's issue, you should post it as answer

Comment: instead of body have you tried  $("form").submit(function(event){

Comment: Should be `$("#login-form").submit()` or `$("#login-form").on('submit')`

Comment: FYI, I don't think `$("body").on('submit','body',function(event){...});` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)**:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can
>   be submitted either by clicking an explicit ,
>   , or , or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form elements have focus.

So, you should use `.submit()` for `<form>` elements:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(event){
    console.log("login clicked");
});
```

---

Seem like your form has been added dynamically, if yes then you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$("body").on('submit','#login-form',function(event) {
    console.log("login clicked");
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work, tried using it and it did not fire the log ( had tried it before).

Answer (score 4):

The submit event is not fired on the `<button>` it's fired on the `<form>`.

in your example the submit event bubbles up to the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-signin').submit() will work.
```

the submit event belongs to the form, not the submit button

Comment: same here, tested and not firing.  ( had tested adding it to form also, but nothing.

Comment: try adding `return false;` after `console.log("login clicked");` that will prevent the form from submitting (and the page reloading)